# Issue while displaying html format using JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl

```
<%String content = content.getBody();%>
```

where "body" is a string containg html markup.

```
body="<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><html><head/><body><p> Hi Firstname Lastname,</p><p>You have requested to change your password</p><p>test content</p></body></html>"
```

when I display it on JSP using `<%=content%>`, it considers html markup and prints the content as expected as follows:

**Output: **
    Hi FirstName, lastName,
    You have requested to change your password.
    test content

However when I tried doing the same using JSTL's c:out as follows:

```
<c:out value="${content.body}"/>
```

It ignores html format and prints the content of string "body" with all the html tags like p,html etc. Basically, it considers it as plain string and displays the content. I want my JSP to apply html tags and display accordingly.

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<c:out value="${content.body}" escapeXml="false" />
```

As `<c:out>` uses XML escaping for the characters '<' and '>'.